# Воспроизведение звука в input при фокусе

Tags: javascript, html, аудио

У меня есть 3 текстовых поля, есть в корне звук. Не получается реализовать следующее: если поле в фокусе, должен однократно воспроизвестись звук. Делал так, но не работает:

JS:

```
function click() {
    new Audio('click.mp3').play();
}
```

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input name="86" type="text"  id="pole1"  onfocus="click();">
    <input name="95" type="text"  id="pole2" >
    <input name="71" type="text"  id="pole3" onfocus="click();">
</form>
```

Comment: Смени название функции на другое. Например, `function onFocus() {` и `onfocus="onFocus();"`. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/04k3rb5f/). Стоит упомянуть, что inilne JS считается устаревшим и не приветствуется.

Comment: Заработало, благодарю.

Comment: обязательно отмечу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Достаточно сменить название функции на другое. Например:

JS:

```
function onFocus() {
    new Audio('click.mp3').play();
}
```

HTML:

```
<input name="86" type="text"  id="pole1"  onfocus="onFocus();">
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/04k3rb5f/).

Почему не работает именно с названием функции `click` - не очень понятно.